# Could Not Instantiate Mail Function - PHPMailer - With Attachments - Only Google Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, email, phpmailer

I have an odd problem, I am using PHPMailer to send an email with a few attachements. The attachments are uploaded to a form using jQuery which works fine and the files get uploaded. When I use IE and Firefox the emails is sent without a problem however when I use Google Chrome I get the error message "Could Not Instantiate Mail Funcition", which I thought was odd.

However when I remove the attachment part of the script the email sends fine in all browsers, therefore I would presume that the problem occurs when PHPMailer tries to attach the files to the form therefore I ran some tests to make sure that the files are definitely uploaded and do exist and those tests came back fine.

```
<?php
$attachment_location = "files/";
$attachments = $_POST["files"];
require_once('../includes/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer(true); 
try {
$mail ->isMail();
$body = '    
<html>
    <head>
        <title>New Account Application Submitted</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                font-family: Arial;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>New Account Application Submitted</h1>
        <p>A user completed the account application form please see the attached documents</p>
        <p>Thank You</p>
    </body>
</html>
        ';
$mail->SetFrom('myemail@email.com');
$address = "myemail@email.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address);
$mail->Subject = "New Account Application Submitted";
$mail->AltBody = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; 
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
foreach($attachments as $attachment){
    if(file_exists($attachment_location . $attachment)){ 
        $mail->AddAttachment($attachment_location . $attachment);  
    }else{
        echo "File does not exist " . $attachment_location . $attachment . "<br>";
    }
}
$mail->Send();
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
  echo $e->errorMessage();
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
foreach($attachments as $attachment){
    unlink($attachment_location . $attachment);  
}
echo "Your application has been received<br> a member of our team will be in contact with you shortly";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not handling your file uploads correctly. Read the PHP [file uploading docs](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php), and follow the [send file upload example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps) provided with PHPMailer.

Make sure that your form has an `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute and that you include a `<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />` input tag.

Then use `move_uploaded_file` and don't try to use the contents of `$_FILES` directly.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I have looked into what you said, I am using a jQuery plugin to handle the file upload by BlueImp https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload, it has a built in function to do something once the file has uploaded completely, I messed with that to only allow the form to submit once it has fully completed and that did the trick in Google Chrome, thanks